# How to see when an interface went down - Debian

Tags: logging, interface, debian

Is there a way to check when an interface went down? 
eth0 went down for some reason and I need to know when that happened.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in terminal.

```
tail  /var/log/syslog -n 1000 | grep down
```

It show down time log for network interface.

```
root@host:~$ tail  /var/log/syslog -n 1000 | grep down
Aug 21 16:25:22 host org.freedesktop.PackageKit[1868]: INFO:Shutting down because of inactivity
Aug 21 17:44:28 host nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 21 17:44:28 host nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug 21 17:45:20 host kernel: [30576.121063] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
Aug 21 17:45:24 host nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 21 17:45:24 host nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
```

If you need log for any specific network interface

```
root@host:~$ tail  /var/log/syslog -n 200 | grep enp2s0
```

It will show  more information(up time,down time and other) for network 
interface "enp2s0"